# Remove Time From Pandas DateTime on Excel Export

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas Dataframe queried with  pyODBC that returns 'dates' as floats. I change the data types to datetime after converting to a string with ymd formatting and then create an Excel File with ExcelWriter. The resulting Excel data keeps the yyyymmdd 00:00:00 format.  Some posts suggest creating 'helper' columns in Pandas and using dt.normalize (?) but I would like to do it all on export ... possible?  Better way in general?

Note [date] is a list of three columns

```
df[date] = df[date].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.astype(str), format = '%Y%m%d'))

df Col 1

2017-01-19 
2016-12-29 
2017-01-04
2016-12-29
2017-01-04  

writer = ExcelWriter('MyData.xlsx', date_format = 'yyyy mm dd')

df.to_excel(writer, 'DATA')

writer.save()

2017-01-19 00:00:00
2016-12-29 00:00:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00
2016-12-29 00:00:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00
2017-01-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is problem `pandas` use `datetime`, so need define `datetime_format` also.

[Docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html).

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MyData.xlsx', 
                        date_format = 'yyyy mm dd', 
                        datetime_format='yyyy mm dd')
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Is there a way to do it while reading the document, or without using the ExcelWriter object.